# Processing IntList.remove() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 10 exception

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a small shooting game in Processing, when I click the mouse button, I create some bullets that travel up the screen, when they get out of the screen they should disappear, I use an `IntList` where I keep the values like that: `(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ...)`, my problem is that when in the code below I try to remove the indexes of the bullet I randomly get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 10` exception, even though I checked the IntList's size before removing. Any help?

```
    for(i = 1; i < shots.size(); i += 2){
      shots.sub(i, bullet_speed);
      if(shots.get(i) + bullet_height <= border_size){
        shots.remove(i); //Problematic point
        println("Removed Y-pos, array's size: "+shots.size());
        shots.remove(i - 1);
        println("Removed X-pos, array's size: "+shots.size());
        i -= 2;
        continue;
      }
      rect(shots.get(i - 1), shots.get(i), bullet_width, bullet_height);
    }
```

**Edit:**
I think I found a clue: the exception occurs always when I reach having 5 bullets on the screen (at the moment, the size of shots becomes 10).

Comment: What does shots.sub() do? Does it change the list?

Comment: @eran shots.sub() decrements bullet's Y-position

Comment: What is IntList? Is it a class you created or some library class? If you crated it, please include its code.

Comment: @eran It's a Processing Class as I understood. https://www.processing.org/reference/IntList.html

Comment: I suggest that you move your debug prints to be before the line that throws the exception, and see what's the value of `i` and `shots.size()` at this point.

Comment: @eran Already did it. What I got `Size: 10, index: 1`, index is `i`.

Comment: I suggest you switch to using an ArrayList<Integer> instead of this IntList. It's possible this class behaves different than ArrayList, and the docs in the link you posted are far from being sufficient. If you make the code work with ArrayList, you can later move back to IntList (if you really want to).

Comment: @eran it looks like I found the problem and the solution, see my answer below if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually funny cause I thought IntList was dynamic as ArrayList is said to be from the Processing documentation, as seen [here](https://www.processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) under **Description**, as suggested by @Eran I moved to ArrayList to test, then in the Java documentations I discovered that my initial declaration `shots = new IntList();` which I thought was variable is actually a declaration for an initial capacity of 10 as stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29), so that's why I was getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 10` exception, now I solved with declarating `shots = new IntList(20);`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for(i = 1; i < shots.size(); i += 2){
```

To:

```
for(i = 0; i < shots.size(); i += 2){
```

List's index starts at 0, not 1. And since you raise by 2 every time, it goes beyond the point of `i < shots.size()` in the for-loop and your `if-statement`, since it only checks the value + 1, not the value + 2 as well.

Comment: My savior! This thing was driving me mad for like 2 days. Just another question: do you know what the 10 in `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 10` stands for? Cause I also got `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: -2` once.

Comment: Glad I could help. The 10 stands for the index that causes the error. In your case the List is of size 10, and it tries to do `.remove(10);` (Arrays and Lists uses indexes from 0 to length-1, so with a List of size 10, it has the indexes 0 to 9 [inclusive], and 10 causes the error. -2 will also cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, since it's also outside the range of 0 to 9 [inclusive] (negative values will always cause the ArrayIndexOufOfBoundsException, since the indexes start at 0).

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the problem, since if you start with i=0, `shots.remove(i - 1)` would give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when i==0.

Comment: Ok, I thought I solved the problem, but I get the exception again... checked the code with a println(), index to remove is < than the size of IntList, could it be something else? Is there a way I can just skip the exception?

Comment: @Eran I changed my code to avoid that, but the problem is another, see my edit in the question.

Comment: @Eran Ah, you're indeed right.. And I just noticed that in the `if-statement` it accesses the same `if(shots.get(i) ...`, so it shouldn't give the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the `.remove(i)` inside the if, since it should had already failed at the `.get(i)`.. Without knowing when it's going inside the if and when not, it's also a bit hard to debug locally, since in the for-loop it does `i += 2` and inside the if-statement it does `i -= 2;`, so when I test it locally with the if-statement as true, it stays at index 1 the entire loop..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm doing `i -= 2` because I suppose that `.remove(i)` reindexes the array so I need to go back